# Passing different objects of the same parent class to a constructor/method that hosts a generic derived class object

Tags: c#

We have the parent class

```
public class ParentClass
{
    int GeneralVariable;
}
```

then a derived class (just a class that holds information)

```
public class DerivedClassOne : ParentClass
{
    int DerivedSpecificVariableOne;
}
```

then another derived class (just a class that holds information)

```
public class DerivedClassTwo : ParentClass
{
    int DerivedSpecificVariableTwo;
}
```

Then a class that can "house" only one of these 2 derived classes:

```
public class HousingClass : UnrelatedImportantClass
{
    public void DoWorkingOnDerivedClasses(){}
}
```

Then a class that hosts everything. HostClass will call methods on HousingClass to do work on DerivedClass

```
public class HostClass
{
    List<HousingClass> Housings = new List<HousingClass>();
}
```

In this housing class, I'd like to be able to "house" either DerivedClassOne, or DerivedClassTwo, and to be able to "do work" on either of the derived classes. Ideally, I'd like to not have to potentially have a ton of overloaded c-tors or methods, with a ton of class variables defining different derived classes. Right now, that's how the "Housing" class is looking, and I foresee it becoming unwieldy and hard to maintain in the near future.

Ultimately, what design principle am I after, and simple case what could that look like? Right now the ParentClass is not Abstract, but would that help in what I'm after?

Comment: You want the HousingClass work with only derived classes and not with the parent class?

Comment: You can either pass the base class or use an interface.

Comment: Chetan, If i can do work on derived classes, wouldn't that also mean I get access to parent class, as well?

Jonathan, When I try passing the base class, I can only do work on base class information and not the derived class information. Though I very well could be implementing that aspect wrong?

Comment: @Surlistyc Then you need to elaborate on the difference between your base and derived two classes. Since we don't know what your "derived specific variable" is. A use case would be better for describing a use case. Because using Interface or base class means you have a contract to do the same thing with different implementations.

Comment: So really, all derived classes WILL have ParentClass information that is used at one point or another, but the information in the derived class is specific to that class. A use case would be something like, 
LivingBeing(ParentClass)
Has age, weight, etc...

Human(DerivedClass)
Has Lexicon, Job, etc...

Snake(DerivedClass)
Has Venom, eggs

Answer (score 0):

Generic class would partially satisfy your requirements - your "housing" class would still be limited to using "parent" methods, but outside callers would be able to use methods/properties of correct derived class.

```
public class HousingClass<T> where T : ParentClass
{
    public T Derived {get;set;}

    public void Method()
    {
      // can only use methods/properties from ParentClass
      Console.WriteLine(Derived.GeneralVariable);
    }
}
```

You will be able to use exact type of `Derived` outside the class so:

```
DerivedClassOne d = new DerivedClassOne();
HousingClass<DerivedClassOne> house = new HousingClass<DerivedClassOne>
     {  Derived = d };
house.Derived.DerivedSpecificVariableOne = 42;
```

Comment: Is it possible to make a `Housing<int>` and a `Housing<string>` in an array or list? OP did not elaborate on use case, but this could be a possible reason OP needs a  `Housing` class.

Comment: The ParentClass and DerivedClass are just data classes. So, the HousingClass is where I actually want to act on some of these variables. sometimes on the ParentClass variables, sometimes on the DerivedClass variables, depending on the workflow. 
The HousingClass already inherits another class that isn't related to the ParentClass. I realize now that I really should have initially put that in the question as that's important.

Housing class will be one of many objects in a list in another class that uses it them.

Comment: @Surlistyc It's still unclear how you hope to make `public void DoWorkingOnDerivedClasses(){}` to work.... Basically having single class magically being at the same time general and able to work with each and every property of all classes derived from `ParentClass` is very confusing. Also I'm not sure how "The HousingClass already inherits another class that isn't related to the ParentClass" - is relevant to my post...

Comment: I supposed that's where I'm stuck. What I was referring to the inheritance was, that I can't have
public class HousingClass<T> where T : ParentClass

because it's already inheriting "UnrelatedImportantClass"

or would there be another way to write the class stub?
public class HousingClass<T> where T : ParentClass : UnrelatedImportantClass
?

Also, why can I only use ParentClass specific from inside the class, and can use derived specific from outside? Legitimate question.